# conditional statement with for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, for-loop, conditional-statements

Not sure what I am doing wrong here;

I am trying to make a for loop with conditional statements for the following functions. I want to make it though so `h` is not a vector. I am doing this for 1 through 5 with increment 0.1.

```
Y = f(h) = h^2    if h <= 2 or h >= 3
Y = f(h) = 45     otherwise
```

my code is

```
for h = 0:0.1:5
if h <= 2;
   Y = h^2;
elseif h >= 3;
Y = h^2;
else;
   h = 45;
end
end
```

Comment: h has to start at 1; Matlab requirement. In your "else" condition, did you mean Y = 45? It looks like the loop will never reach this else condition since h>=3 will be true until h is equal to 5.

Comment: `for start:inc:end \ ...`, like that, none of those have to be 1, nor even integers.

Comment: also OP has `Y = f(t) = h^2`, a function of `t` that's not even using the variable `t`

Comment: oh god yes you're right I had in mind an error I got about my start: value but of course it can be anything thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done easier, but with a for loop i think you could use:

```
h=0:0.1:5;
y=zeros(1,length(h));

for i=1:length(h)
    if or(h(i) <= 2, h(i) >= 3)
       y(i) = h(i)^2;
    else
       y(i) = 45;
    end
end
```

Comment: for an even more matlab-y answer: `h=0:0.1:5; y = h.^2; y(h >= 2 & h <= 3) = 45;`

Comment: thats nice MATLAB style of course, but he wants to use for-loops :)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to avoid making `h` an array? MATLAB specializes in operations on arrays. In fact, [vectorized operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) in MATLAB are generally faster than `for` loops, which I found counter-intuitive having started coding in C++.

An example of a vectorized verison of your code could be:

```
h = 0:0.1:5;
inds = find(h > 2 & h < 3);  % grab indices where Y = 45
Y = h.^2;  % set all of Y = h^2
Y(inds) = 45;  % set only those entries for h between 2 and 3 to 45
```

The period in the  `.^2` operator broadcasts that operator to every element in the `h` array. This means that you end up squaring each number in `h` individually. In general, vectorized operation like this are more efficient in MATLAB, so it is probably best to get in the habit of vectorizing your code.

Finally, you could reduce the above code a bit by not storing your indices:

```
h = 0:0.1:5;
Y = h.^2;  % set all of Y = h^2
Y(find(h > 2 & h < 3)) = 45;  % set only those entries for h between 2 and 3 to 45
```

[This blog series](http://www.matlabtips.com/the-art-of-vectorizing-part-1/) seems to be a good primer on vectorizing your MATLAB code.